# Cells property in range property syntax not working in excel objects but working in Modules

Tags: vba, excel

Syntax ,

```
Sheets("Working1").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(5, 5)).Select
```

This Syntax is not working in Microsoft Excel objects but working in modules. Why?

Please anyone help.

Comment: Probably `Sheets("Working1")` is not the activesheet. Do you expect excel to select the range in Working1 even if it is not the activesheet.

Comment: try something that does not require a worksheet to be active, like this ... `Sheets("Working1").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(5, 5)).Interior.Color = vbred`

Comment: tried this one also but Same error is populating - Application defined or Object defined error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate the sheet before you can select the range on the sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectRange()

    'What will be better is to reference the WorkBook as well.
    With Sheets("Working1")
        'Activate the sheet before selecting the range
        .Activate
        'You need to reference the WorkBook and WorkSheet
        'Also notice the . before the cells _
                by using the with statement this references the cells in the Working1 Sheet
        .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(5, 5)).Select

    End With

End Sub

Sub SelectRange()

    'Without the with statement
    Sheets("Working1").Activate
    Sheets("Working1").Range(Sheets("Working1").Cells(2, 2), Sheets("Working1").Cells(5, 5)).Select


End Sub
```

Comment: Sheets("Working1").Activate
Sheets("Working1").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(5, 5)).select       - I tried this too but no use

Comment: @pramodkarna you need to reference the `Sheet` inside the range object. I have edited my answer for you to see easier.

Comment: @pramodkarna glad it worked. Enjoy stack overflow. Remember to upvote all answer which are helping you in your learning and the ones you select as correct for your answers.